# Inserting values with select statement with specific data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data into a specific table. That table create an identity key for the customer data.

For Example:

I have a table called table3 which have columns such as ID, GroupID, InsertDate, UpdateDate, ProfileID

I am having a select query

```
   Insert into table 
    (GroupID, InsertDate, ProfileID)
    with resultsOne AS (select GroupID, GetDate() as InsertDate from table1 t1 
where GroupID ="1007")
    , resultsTwo AS (select Distinct ProfileID from table2 t2)
        select t1.*, t2.* from resultsOne, resultsTwo
```

I have overall 14,000 records in Profile table. Based on that I wanted to insert 14,000 records but instead it is inserting 800,000 records. So how can I generate an ID for 14,000 records only?

Table looks like something like this.

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+    ID     +  GroupID  +    InsertedDare          +    UpdatedDate    +     ProfileID     +
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+     1     +   1007    +  2016-09-18 16:33:33.967 +        NULL       +     67885612      +
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+     2     +   1007    +  2016-09-18 16:34:33.967 +        NULL       +     67885613      +
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+     3     +   1007    +  2016-09-18 16:35:33.967 +        NULL       +     67885617      +
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+     4     +   1007    +  2016-09-18 16:36:33.967 +        NULL       +     67885618      +
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

ID to Updatedate is from table1 and ProfileID is from table2.

Comment: What is the relation between table1 and table2?

Comment: There is no relation between  table1 and table2 they are seperate data. Technically there is but if you are talking based on SQL data mapping or inner join then there is no relation.

Comment: I don't know which table is the Profile table mentioned in your question, but 14000 rows will be inserted only if the other table has 1 row.  The `CROSS JOIN` will multiply the number of rows in table1 by the number of rows in table2. If that's not your intent, you need an `INNER JOIN` or `WHERE` clause.

Comment: How? So, any groupid can have any profile id? Looks like the quesiton is not complete.

Comment: GroupID for different purpose.Each unique groupid should have 1  ID which is identity key is generated from table.

Answer (score 0):

When you Insert using CTE syntax should be like this

```
;with cte as
(
select ...
)
Insert into tablename(col1,..)
Select col1,.. from cte
```

Here is the correct way

```
;WITH resultsone 
     AS (SELECT Distinct groupid, 
                Getdate() AS InsertDate 
         FROM   table1 t1), 
     resultstwo 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT profileid 
         FROM   table2 t2) 
INSERT INTO table 
            (groupid, 
             insertdate, 
             profileid) 
SELECT t1.groupid, 
       t1.InsertDate 
       t2.profileid 
FROM   resultsone t1 
       CROSS JOIN resultstwo t2
```

Few things to consider

- Always add the column list in both `Insert` & `Select` when you are inserting  records
- Use `Cross Join` to get a *Cartesian* product of two tables instead of old stlye comma separated join

Comment: Tried. That didn't work. I needed to insert only 14,000 records which is in table2 but somehow it is getting more than 14,000 records

Comment: Then you are missing join condition. What is the relationship between table1 & table2

Comment: There is no relation between table1 and table2 they are seperate data. Technically there is but if you are talking based on inner join then there is no relation.

Comment: @user1413 Added Distinct to first table may be thats the mistake.. check now

Comment: Updated desciption. Hope it helps what I am doing. Thanks